# Negation with If logic in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am trying to filter out a string based on some criteria. I just want throw an error when there is not a 'c' after the second '/' or the string does not start with 'a'. Here is what I am doing -

```
if sample_data.split('/')[2] != 'c' or sample_data[:1] != 'a':
    print('Unexpected data')
    exit()

print('Further processing')
```

here is output based on the input I pass -

```
sample_data = 'a/b/c/d output - Further processing --> AS EXPECTED
sample_data = 'x/b/y/d output - Unexpected data --> AS EXPECTED
sample_data = 'a/b/y/d output - Unexpected data --> NOT AS EXPECTED
sample_data = 'x/b/c/d output - Unexpected data --> NOT AS EXPECTED
```

I guess I am missing something basic here.

Comment: I think you are using 'or' wrong here (in your natural language description). You want to throw an error when the string does not start with 'a' _and_ when it does not have 'c' after the second '/'.

Comment: Hey Dan - your `if` statement is actually executing correctly, per your description. The first failed example does not have `c` after the second `/`. The second failed example does not start with `a`. Is this not your criteria? Like @UziGoozie said, you may be looking for `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: @UziGoozie - When the string starts with 'a' it does not matter if there is 'c' or not. It should be valid. Same with if there is a 'c' in the position then does not matter if there is an 'a' in the beginning.

Comment: @gmdev - yes in the first failed example it does not have a 'c' in that position but since it starts with 'a' it should be valid. Same with the second failed scenario. Maybe i am using the if statement wrong

Comment: ok. this is weird. Using and works. But "and" evaluates both the conditions and if both are true then it returns true. If the first check is false it does not check the second condition since it will always return false. is my understanding wrong here?

Comment: @Dan your understanding is correct. If you're checking checking that the characters aren't there, and you want either character present, then it failing the first condition (and not checking the second) is a desired condition and correct for your purposes because failing the first condition means one of the characters is there.

Comment: @Dan for a little expansion of logic, you're checking for `not (p or q)` where p = "c is in the right place" and q = "a is in the right place", which can also be represented by its logical negation: `not (p or q) == (not p and not q)`

Comment: @Dan you said "When the string starts with 'a' it does not matter if there is 'c' or not. It should be valid." So in other words for it to generate an error It shouldn't start with 'a' AND the 'c' can't be in that position. So `if sample_data.split('/')[2] != 'c' and sample_data[:1] != 'a':` would be the correct conditions to generate an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In natural language, you'd say:

The data is valid if it starts with an `a` **OR** it contains a `c` in the third location. When you invert this, you need to use [de Morgan's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
not(A or B) = not(A) and not(B)
```

In words: The data is *invalid* if it *doesn't* start with `a` **AND** it doesn't contain `c` in the third location.

To verify this, let's make a truth table:

| `sample_data.split('/')[2] != 'c'` (Doesn't contain `c`) | `sample_data[:1] != 'a'` (Doesn't start with `a`) | Result (throw error?) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `c` (False) | `a` (False) | Valid (False) |
| `c` (False) | `*` (True) | Valid (False) |
| `*` (True) | `a` (False) | Valid (False) |
| `*` (True) | `*` (True) | Invalid (True) |

The only case where you want an error is when `sample_data.split('/')[2] != 'c'` **and** `sample_data[:1] != 'a'`. That's what your `if` statement needs to have.

```
samples = [
    'a/b/c/d',
    'x/b/c/d',
    'a/b/y/d', 
    'x/b/y/d',
]

for sample_data in samples:
    print(f"Input: {sample_data}", end=" ")
    if sample_data.split('/')[2] != 'c' and sample_data[:1] != 'a':
        print('Output: Unexpected data')
    else:
        print('Output: Further processing')
```

gives what you expect:

```
Input: a/b/c/d Output: Further processing
Input: x/b/c/d Output: Further processing
Input: a/b/y/d Output: Further processing
Input: x/b/y/d Output: Unexpected data
```